# Make divs fit available space?

Tags: html, css

I have a number of divs with varying height but fixed width, as such:

```
---- ----
|  | |  |
|  | ----
----
```

I want them to fill the page as follows:

```
---- ----
|  | |  |
|  | ----
---- ----
---- |  |
|  | ----
----
```

...but I can't seem to get past getting them to fill like this:

```
---- ----
|  | |  |
|  | ----
----         
---- ----
|  | |  |
---- ----
```

I'd prefer not to group them into columns. Is there a CSS rule that would allow them to dynamically fill the space above?

EDIT: Thanks for the quick responses.

I asked specifically for a CSS hack just to avoid jQuery. It's a rather trivial jQuery problem (My jQuery is better than my CSS!), was just wondering if I could do it with CSS alone.

Comment: Yet another one of these questions...

Comment: what if they are dynamic

Comment: It could be that you have set a bottom margin on the right box.

Comment: Please provide code to replicate the issue, preferably with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or some other live example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2LYEq/ suppose divs are of dynamic height

Comment: Here's mdesdev's idea of wrapping them in columns in action: http://jsfiddle.net/777SW/1/

Comment: The only solution I know is to give them a `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` with Top and left coordinates, and after that you'll need CSS so this isn't a real solution.

Comment: @gaynorvader when I said wrap them I meant this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/RKyzp/) ;)

Comment: how about use flexbox if possible made just for this

Comment: @mdesdev my mistake! Though with fixed width, columns make the most sense.

Comment: If you have just 2 columns, you can float left the left ones and float right the right ones

Comment: See this solution. Hope this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/4c3Wu/

Answer (score 2):

You can can always use CSS3 columns, just like so:

```
<!-- html -->
.container>.item*5{lorem}

<!-- css -->
.container { column-count: 3; column-gap: 1em; }
.container .item { column-break-inside: avoid; }
```

Take a look at this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/36ru7/embedded/result/)

The only down side to this, obviously, is browser support, as a lot of browsers do not support this stuff yet, so you should fallback to a javascript solution, something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) should work just fine.

Comment: +1 for providing a real html5 solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float: left;` to all of these divs.

I can provide more help if you share your code.

Comment: Float left won't stack them vertically

Comment: This is what will happen, if he just floats them: http://jsfiddle.net/shLKW/

Comment: Will check and respond asap jsfiddle.net loads..

Answer (score -1):

Float:left is the best option.

---

|  | |  |
|  | ----

---

---- |  |

### |  | ----

another example if you want this pattern to the other div tag apart from other div tags, then you can use **clear:left** css property it's used to clear the float value for the particlular div you mention ,so you can use the this pattern for the last div tag.

Answer (score -2):

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/shLKW/3/ I hope this will help for you.

```
A<div style="width:100px; height: 80px;">
    <div style="height:80px;width:50px;background:#000;float:left; color:white">1</div>
    <div style="height:50px;width:50px;background:#ff0000;float:left">2</div>
</div>   

<div style="width:100px">

    <div style="height:50px;width:50px;background:#aeaeae;float:left">3</div>
    <div style="height:50px;width:50px;background:#666;float:left">4</div>

</div>
```